# After updating to nHibernate 4, cannot use ManyToMany Mappings. Could not determine type

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

After updating to nHibernate (4.0.2.4000 via nuget), the many to many mappings that previously worked now cause mapping exception "Could not determine type for: nHibernateManyToMany.IRole, nHibernateManyToMany, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(id)"

Seems to be only for many to many, and when the List is a interface (i.e. List<Role> vs List<IRole>).

Example code that now fails:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration().SetProperty(Environment.ReleaseConnections, "on_close")
                                               .SetProperty(Environment.Dialect, typeof(SQLiteDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                                               .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(SQLite20Driver).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                                               .SetProperty(Environment.CollectionTypeFactoryClass, typeof(DefaultCollectionTypeFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                                               .SetProperty(Environment.CommandTimeout, "0");

        var mapper = new ModelMapper();

        mapper.AddMappings(new[] { typeof(EmployeeMapping), typeof(RoleMapping) });

        var hbmMapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

        hbmMapping.autoimport = false;

        configuration.AddMapping(hbmMapping);

        // this line will fail
        var factory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<IRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public interface IRole
{
    int Id { get; set; } 
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Role : IRole
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeMapping : ClassMapping<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMapping()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id, x =>
        {
            x.Type(NHibernateUtil.Int32);
            x.Generator(Generators.Identity);
            x.Column("EmployeeId");
        });

        Bag(x => x.Roles, m =>
        {
            m.Table("EmployeeRole");
            m.Key(km =>
            {
                km.Column("EmployeeId");
                km.NotNullable(true);
                km.ForeignKey("FK_Role_Employee");
            });
            m.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Lazy);
        }, er => er.ManyToMany(m =>
        {
            m.Class(typeof(Role));
            m.Column("RoleId");
        }));
    }
}

public class RoleMapping : ClassMapping<Role>
{
    public RoleMapping()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id, x =>
        {
            x.Type(NHibernateUtil.Int32);
            x.Generator(Generators.Identity);
            x.Column("RoleId");
        });

        Property(x => x.Description, c =>
        {
            c.Length(50);
            c.NotNullable(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions about where we could look for details on how this has changed since v3 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a bug in nHibernate.

A pull request has been submitted here https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/385